How to set the position of object in a WebView2 control?
I am trying to set the position of a moveable object inside a WebView2 control on a Winforms app.  As of right now it appears out of the viewable area without scrolling down on the page.
I have tried several variations of this:
WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('widget_control')style=inset: '10px auto auto 10px';")

However, the position of the object still remains the same.

You gotta set the element's style.position to absolute and then set the style.top and style.left to some new coordinates(wherever you're trying to move it to).
For example, this'll move it to coords in pixels(px) 40 on the x and 40 on the y:
WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('widget_control').style = 'position:absolute; top:40px; left:40px';");

